# Inserting circles on mouse click using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Just started learning this language today (I'm sorry if this is a stupid question), but I'm trying to figure out how to insert circles onto a webpage. I found an example code here: http://jsfiddle.net/7xQZ2/
However, when I try to run it from a single file, the script portion isn't running for some reason. I tried changing around the `<body>` and `<script>`. It's simply displaying a box with the coordinates (0,0). It stays static and it isn't changing when I move my mouse.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <h2 id="status2">0, 0</h2>
    <canvas width="500px" height="500px" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border:1px ridge green;" id="special">
    </canvas>
</head>

<body> 
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
             $("#special").click(function(e){ 

                var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop; 

                /* var c=document.getElementById("special"); */
                var ctx= this.getContext("2d"); /*c.getContext("2d");*/
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(x, y, 10,0, 2*Math.PI);
                ctx.stroke();
                $('#status2').html(x +', '+ y); 
           }); 
        })  
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The HTML goes between the body tags and the script goes between the head tags.

Comment: wh-why is your body content in your `<head>` tag?

Comment: First of all, you are relying upon the jQuery library and did not include it.  Secondly, you have invalid html because you have elements in <head>.  Figure those out and it may work.

Comment: When you want to see a jsFiddle example as a stand alone web page, append `/show/light/` to the end of it. In your case, `http://fiddle.jshell.net/7xQZ2/show/light/`. Then you can right click and view the real source without all the extra stuff that the jsFiddle test environment gives you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jQuery. Place this line in the `head` section:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Also move what you have place in `head` to `body`, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using the [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/) library. Be sure to include it before using your code.

Also, all HTML elements that are going to be in your page need to be in the *body* tag, not the *head* one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h2 id="status2">0, 0</h2>
    <canvas width="500px" height="500px" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border:1px ridge green;" id="special">
    </canvas>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
             $("#special").click(function(e){ 

                var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop; 

                /* var c=document.getElementById("special"); */
                var ctx= this.getContext("2d"); /*c.getContext("2d");*/
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(x, y, 10,0, 2*Math.PI);
                ctx.stroke();
                $('#status2').html(x +', '+ y); 
           }); 
        })  
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got only this as your HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <h2 id="status2">0, 0</h2>
    <canvas width="500px" height="500px" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border:1px ridge green;" id="special">
    </canvas>
</head>

<body> 
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
             $("#special").click(function(e){ 

                var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop; 

                /* var c=document.getElementById("special"); */
                var ctx= this.getContext("2d"); /*c.getContext("2d");*/
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(x, y, 10,0, 2*Math.PI);
                ctx.stroke();
                $('#status2').html(x +', '+ y); 
           }); 
        })  
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Then yes, it won't work. Because the code you're using belong to jQuery library of JavaScript. Which requires you to have jQuery included in your code. It is not built-in each Browser.

Use this code to add it.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```